# psycopg2 error: DatabaseError: error with no message from the libpq

Tags: python, postgresql, celery, python-multiprocessing, psycopg

I have an application that parses and loads data from csv files into a Postgres 9.3 database.  In serial execution insert statements/cursor executions work without an issue.

I added celery in the mix to add parallel parsing and inserting of the data files.  Parsing works fine. However, I go to run insert statements and I get:

```
[2015-05-13 11:30:16,464:  ERROR/Worker-1] ingest_task.work_it: Exception
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ingest_tasks.py", line 86, in work_it
        rowcount = ingest_data.load_data(con=con, statements=statements)
    File "ingest_data.py", line 134, in load_data
        ingest_curs.execute(statement)
    DatabaseError: error with no message from the libpq
```

Answer (score 22):

I encountered a similar problem when multiprocessing `engine.execute()`. I solved this problem finally by just adding `engine.dispose()` right in the first line under the function where the subprocess is supposed to enter, as suggested in the [official document](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#engine-disposal):

> When a program uses multiprocessing or `fork()`, and an `Engine` object is 
>   copied to the child process, `Engine.dispose()` should be called so that the 
>   engine creates brand new database connections local to that fork. Database 
>   connections generally do **not** travel across process boundaries.

Comment: Exactly. And this will occur with any multiprocessing/worker and database connection setup. You'll generally need to create a new db connection on a per process basis.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, thanks for the documentation link.

Comment: In my case, it was as simple as putting `engine.dispose` in the `initilizer` argument for mutliprocessing pool, e.g. `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=42, initializer=db.engine.dispose)`