# Multiprocessing with flask sqlalchemy - psycopg2.DatabaseError: error with status PGRES_TUPLES_OK and no message from the libpq

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restplus

am getting below exception while trying to use multiprocessing with flask sqlalchemy.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
[12/Aug/2019 18:09:52] "GET /api/resources HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.3.6-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.3.6-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.DatabaseError: error with status PGRES_TUPLES_OK and no message from the libpq
```

Without multiprocessing the code works perfect, but when i add the multiprocessing as below, am running into this issue.

```
worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=<target_method_which_has_business_logic_with_DB>, args=(data,), name='PROCESS_ID', daemon=False)
worker.start()
return Response("Request Accepted", status=202)
```

I see an answer to similar question in SO (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33331954/8085047), which suggests to use engine.dispose(), but in my case am using db.session directly, not creating the engine and scope manually.

Please help to resolve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: sounds like the worker (or something else) is closing the connection, https://codewithoutrules.com/2018/09/04/python-multiprocessing/ might be relevant to help understand what's going on behind the scenes

Comment: The above URL gives 404, so here's the updated URL: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Following Sam's link helped me solve it.

Before I had (not working):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(f, [arg1, arg2, ...])
```

This works for me:

```
from multiprocessing import get_context
with get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(f, [arg1, arg2, ...])
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from dibrovsd@github was really useful for me. If you are using a PREFORKING server like uwsgi or gunicorn, this would also help you.

Post his comment here for your reference.

> Found. This happens when uwsgi (or gunicorn) starts when multiple workers are forked from the first process.
> If there is a request in the first process when it starts, then this opens a database connection and the connection is forked to the next process. But in the database, of course, no new connection is opened and a broken connection occurs.
> You had to specify lazy: true, lazy-apps: true (uwsgi) or preload_app = False (gunicorn)
> In this case, add. workers do not fork, but run themselves and open their normal connections themselves

Refer to link: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/281#issuecomment-985387977